# what happens when i compile source code to exe file in .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, compilation, exe

What happens when I compile .NET source code (c# or vb) to .exe file?  I wish to understand the process which happens during making an exe file and have viewed several questions regarding reverse engineering and decompilation (for example, [How do I decompile a .NET EXE into readable C# source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179741/how-do-i-decompile-a-net-exe-into-readable-c-sharp-source-code) and [What happens when user click .NET assembly (EXE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788270/what-happens-when-user-click-net-assembly-exe))

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Managed Execution Process - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5532s8a.aspx)

Comment: Take a look at [How does C# compilation get around needing header files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917935/how-does-c-sharp-compilation-get-around-needing-header-files/1918663#1918663)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The managed execution process includes the following steps

1. Choosing a compiler

   > To obtain the benefits provided by the common language runtime, you must use one or more language compilers that
   >   target the runtime.
2. Compiling your code to MSIL

   > Compiling translates
   >   your source code into Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) and
   >   generates the required metadata.
3. Compiling MSIL to native code

   > At execution time, a just-in-time (JIT) compiler translates the MSIL into
   >   native code. During this compilation, code must pass a verification
   >   process that examines the MSIL and metadata to find out whether the
   >   code can be determined to be type safe.
4. Running code

   > The common language runtime provides the infrastructure that enables execution to
   >   take place and services that can be used during execution.

look here for detailled information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5532s8a.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you may take a look on the following links that i think they are usefull,

1- [Image Describing CLR.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aOverview_of_the_Common_Language_Infrastructure.svg)

2- [Wikipedia Description of .NET Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)

3- [.Net Framework Architecture](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/net-framework-and-architecture/)